# Выбрать столбцы из списка в DataFrame так чтобы не получить ошибку "KeyError: "['colX', 'colY'] not in index""

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, анализ-данных

Есть большой Data Frame = 'StartDataFrame'. Из него, для обработки, я выбираю все столбцы с соц. сетями и тд.

```
AboutCompanyDataFrame = StartDataFrame[['twitter', 'facebook', 'github', 
'reddit', 'medium', 'telegram']]
```

НО в StartDataFrame не всегда присутствует тот или иной столбец (например нет столбца 'telegram' или 'github'...). И выполнение строчки выше, в таком случае, заканчивается ошибкой.

Пожалуйста подскажите способ, как лучше создать AboutCompanyDataFrame содержащий все возможные столбцы из списка ['twitter', 'facebook', 'github', 
'reddit', 'medium', 'telegram'], и не ломающийся если в StartDataFrame нет одного из столбцов. Спасибо заранее!

Comment: А какая ошибка / исключение то было?

Comment: KeyError вроде бы =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Пример:

```
In [217]: cols = ['twitter', 'facebook', 'github', 'reddit', 'medium', 'telegram']

In [218]: df
Out[218]:
  aaa facebook github twitter zzz
0  aa       fb     gh      tw  zz

In [219]: df.loc[:, df.columns.isin(cols)]
Out[219]:
  facebook github twitter
0       fb     gh      tw
```

---

как работает `df.columns.isin(...)`:

```
In [220]: df.columns.isin(cols)
Out[220]: array([False,  True,  True,  True, False])
```

Comment: Как всегда спасибо за ответ! Теперь понятно =)